# Regex: How to match internal substring with only one group if string starts with desired sequence

Tags: python, regex

I am using the python flavor of Regex.

Consider this example string:

`must_start some_random_filler "match this!" end`

I would like to find a match object whose first and only group is `match this!` if the whole string starts with `must_start`.

I have been able to extract the substring `match this!` using two groups:

```
(?<=^must_start)(.*\")(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")
```

Group 1:  `some_random_filler "`

Group 2: `match this!`

Is it possible to have two consecutive positive look behinds? One for checking that the string starts with `must_start` and the other for checking that `match this!` is preceded with a `"`? (`some_random_filler` could be any character sequence). I haven't been able to formulate a successful expression so far.

It's not the end of the world if I have two groups; I am just more curious to know if it's possible. My intuition says yes, but I am only a beginner with regular expressions, hence the question.

Comment: You could use a capturing group without the lookarounds `^must_start[^"]*"([^"]+)"` See https://regex101.com/r/tlEgLl/1 If you have the pypi regex module installed you could use `(?<=^must_start\b[^"]*")[^"]+` See https://rextester.com/RXMT72040

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a lookbehind to get the match between the double quotes by using a capturing group `([^"]+)` and a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

```
^must_start\b[^"]*"([^"]+)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zF5D2e/1)

If you have the [regex pypi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) installed you could use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=^must_start\b[^"]*")[^"]+(?=")
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `^must_start\b` Match from the start `must_start`
  - `[^"]*"` Negated character class, match 0+ times any char except `"`, then match `"`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[^"]+` Negated character class, match 1+ times any char except `"`
- `(?=")` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is `"`

[Python demo](https://rextester.com/HXXJ72325)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the negated character class, and I now see it's potential. Thank you very much for the insight!

Comment: I do get an error however with your second regular expression when testing it on www.regex101.com.

__`*` A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width__

Comment: @FlorentH That is correct because you have to install the pypi module for that to work. You can for example select the  ECMAscript (which is a different engine) to see it working https://regex101.com/r/UZCNGz/1

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp:

```
^must_start.*?"(.*?)".*
```

Comment: Yeah, that’s what @the fourth bird commented 8 minutes earlier.